# Abrir Ficheiro PDF a partir de um valor em TextBox

Tags: excel-vba

Boa noite,

Estou um bocado enrascado a tentar optimizar o meu formulário, o objetivo é mostrar o ficheiro PDF de igual nome correspondente ao valor na Caixa de Texto.
Os ficheiros PDF's estão todos guardados na mesma diretoria de pasta, neste momento estou a usar o WebBroswer porque o AcroPDF não está a funcionar.

Atualmente tenho este código que me abre um ficheiro específico, mas queria otimizar da forma acima mencionada.

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""C:\Users\adhil\OneDrive\Ambiente de Trabalho\Marinha_Carreira\EH\1. Projetos\3. Pessoal\Excels\DMAT.pdf.pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
```

Obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Fiz apenas com a seguinte linha.

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("C:\filepath" & "\" & TextBox1.Value & ".pdf")
```